# How to set SMTP for microk8s grafana (prometheus addon)

Tags: kubernetes, smtp, prometheus, grafana

To use alert by E-mail in Grafana, we have to set SMTP settings in grafana.ini.

On Ubuntu, we can easily run the grafana-prometheus-k8s stack by command
`microk8s enable prometheus`
However, how can we feed grafana.ini to grafana running in a k8s pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can modify grafana k8s deployment manifest by **volumeMounts** to feed grafana.ini on our host to grafana running in a pod.

First, prepare your grafana.ini with SMTP settings. E.g.

```
[smtp]
enabled = true
host = smtp.gmail.com:465
# Please change user and password to your ones.
user = foo@bar.com
password = your-password
```

Then, you can place this file on your host. E.g. `/home/mydir/grafana.ini`

Modify the loaded grafana k8s deployment manifest:

```
kubectl edit deployments.apps -n monitoring grafana
```

Add a new mount to **volumeMounts** (not the one in `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration`):

```
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
          name: mydir
          subPath: grafana.ini
```

Add a new **hostPath** to **volumes**:

```
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /home/mydir
          type: ""
        name: mydir
```

Finally, restart the deployment:

```
kubectl rollout restart -n monitoring deployment grafana
```

Run this command and use a web browser on your host to navigate to http://localhost:8080 to grafana web app:

```
kubectl port-forward -n monitoring svc/grafana 8080:3000
```

Then, you can navigate to Alerting / Notification channels / Add channel to add an Email notification channel and test it!